# Is there a better way than a drop down HTML select to offer website users a long list of links to jump to?

Tags: website-design, lists, html

I am creating a sort of jump page for my team. We need to be able to select from a list of about 20 - 30 portals to jump to from this page. Would the HTML select be the best way to offer that or, as far as UX/Design, is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I did a final count and I was way off. It is 79 links.

Comment: This is cross-posted from GD (please don't cross-post!) and may suffer the same fate as [this very similar question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51575/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-a-usability-problem-when-using-a-large-dropdown-for-tab)

Comment: Sorry, I posted it on Graphic Design before I knew about the UX site. I think that UX would be more appropriate and that is why I re-posted it here. I deleted the other one.

Comment: Is there any way to predict which ones they care about? Can you list recently viewed groups or groups that match their role on the team?

Comment: Unfortunately no. All are used, some more than others but no real way to predict them.

Comment: What kind of links are they? Why is there so many of them?

Comment: Instead of a select drop-down that overlays the existing content, you can have a div the whole width of the page expands open to show a more structured arrangement of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are better ways.

1. If you have a space, group the items into a few groups (3-5) of related links, then list all of them on the pages.

   - Pros: easy to scan the list, everything is visible so no surprises.
   - Cons: needs lots of space, needs a sensible way to group them.
2. List them alphabetically, possibly in columns.

   - Pros: If you know how to spell what you are looking for it's easy to find, uses a commonly understood ordering system, everything is visible with no surprises.
   - Cons: takes up lots of space, alphabetical ordering means it's all one big list.
3. "Type ahead" predictive style inputs.

   - Pros: space saving, less reliant on scrolling and accurate pointer interactions (maybe better for touch), good if you can spell what you are looking for and you know what is in the list.
   - Cons: Content is hidden so you might search for something that isn't there.

Comment: I'm thinking about trying something like #2 suggested here. I'll create a collapsible div using jQuery to toggle it open/close by button click and have it show the list in six columns in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what @edeverett said, but combining all three would be (in my opinion) even better. 79 links is a lot, so sorting them alphabetically and arranging them in groups would clear out some confusion. And to make things easier, you can add a search box right above the the groups of links, which will help users filter out the link they're looking for.
In addition to that, you can give the links some tags too, in case users end up typing unrelated text in the search field (`ps`/`psd` instead of `photoshop`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

maybe you could put them in an alphabetized accordion using something like jQuery.

A-G       * *click to open, drops down showing 'A-G'*

or

Links 1-10 * *click to open, drops down showing '1-10'*